# Delete data from table with foreign keys as primary

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, sql-delete

I am programming a drawing surface with elements and connections between them.

My two tables for the surface look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE element
(
  elid character varying(60) NOT NULL,
  data json,
  surface_id character varying(60) NOT NULL,
  type character varying,
  CONSTRAINT element_primary_key PRIMARY KEY (elid),
)
CREATE TABLE connection
(
  from_elid character varying(60) NOT NULL,
  to_elid character varying(60) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT from_to_element_id PRIMARY KEY (from_elid, to_elid),
  CONSTRAINT from_element_fk FOREIGN KEY (from_elid)
      REFERENCES element (elid) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT to_element_fk FOREIGN KEY (to_elid)
      REFERENCES element (elid) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

If I delete an element on the surface it deletes the corresponding connection as well, which is represented by the `connection` constraints.
In that case I check all the elements with the same `surface_id` and those missing get deleted (as well as their connections).

But how do I delete connections explicitly when being deleted on the drawing surface? Since `from_elid` and `to_elid` are still present in the table `element`?

EDIT: for saving the drawing surface, all elements and connections between them are sent by the client to the server.

Example data in Database:

```
--------------------------------  ---------------------
|element                        | |connection         |
--------------------------------  ---------------------
|elid | data |surface_id |type  | |from_elid |to_elid |
--------------------------------- ---------------------
|e1   |{}    |s1         |xxx   | |e1        |e2      |
|e2   |{}    |s1         |xxx   | |e2        |e3      |
|e3   |{}    |s1         |xxx   | |e3        |e4      |
|e4   |{}    |s1         |xxx   | |..        |..      |
|e5   |{}    |s2         |xxx   | |e5        |e6      |
|e6   |{}    |s2         |xxx   | |e6        |e7      |
|..   |..    |..         |...   | |..        |..      |
--------------------------------- ---------------------
```

Example data sent by the client:

```
{
  surface_id: 's1', 
  elements:['e1','e2','e3','e4'], 
  connections:[
    {from:'e2', to:'e3'},
    {from:'e3', to:'e4'}
  ]
}
```

In the example data the connection between `e1` and `e2` is missing, meaning it was deleted on the drawing surface with the `surface_id` = 's1' and has to be deleted from the table `connection` as well. How to achieve that with the given data AND NOT deleting the connections between elements with `surface_id` = 's2'?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand: "*But deleting a single connection without the connecting elements needs another approach*" - just delete the row from the `connection` table. That won't automatically remove the elements.

Comment: ok, how would your query look like, if you want to delete a connection, if your only information about it being deleted is that it is not sent by the client (only present elements and connections are sent)

Comment: Sorry you need to be more specific than that. What exactly is this "client" thing? And what does it send to the database? If that client talks to the database, then why can't it simply delete the connections no longer needed (with a simple `delete from connection where ...`)

Comment: I see, changed my question again with sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But how do I delete connections explicitly when being deleted on the drawing surface? Since from_elid and to_elid are still present in the table element

You are misunderstanding how a foreign key works. The foreign key from `connection` to `element` states that an element **must** be present if you insert a connection. It does *not* require a connection to exist for every element.

So you can delete rows from the `connection` table any time you want. You just can't delete rows from the `element` table as long as there is at least one connection using that element.

---

**Edit**

If your program only gets the "surviving" connections, you can delete the obsolete ones using the information provided

Assuming you get three connections and you don't know which of them are new and which aren't:

You first need to delete the non-existing ones:

```
delete from connection 
where (from_elid, to_elid) not in ( ('e2', 'e3'), ('e3','e4'), ('e4','e1') )
  and exists (select 1 
              from element e 
              where e.elid in (connection.from_elid, connection.to_elid)
                and e.surface_id = 's1');
```

This will remove all connections for elements on the surface s1 except for those in the `in` clause.

And now you need to insert those connections from that list that do not yet exist in the `connection` table - basically a conditional insert. This can be done using a `insert .. select`:

```
insert into connection (from_elid, to_elid)
select *
from (
  values ('e2', 'e3'), ('e3','e4'), ('e4','e1')
) as t (from_elid, to_elid)
where not exists (select *
                  from connection c
                  where (t.from_elid, t.to_elid) = (c.from_elid, c.to_elid));
```

You do need to properly handle unique key violations in a multi-user environment, because other transactions could insert the same information.

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/64e7d/1

Comment: thanks for the answer, guess my question was not clear enough. See my edit. Btw the constraints `from_elid`is used to delete the conne

Comment: That has been my first approach as well, but that query deletes all connections from other drawing surfaces (determined by `surface_id`),too.

Answer (score 0):

> But how do I delete connections explicitly when being deleted on the
>   drawing surface?

You mean you want to delete those foreign key entries in connection table after their referenced elid entries in element table is deleted?

In any case, if DDL doesn't allow you what you want to achieve, you can consider using triggers like BEFORE DELETE or AFTER DELETE, so that you can clean up the element table first and then connection table or connection table after element table.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I tried to make my question more clear with the edit

Comment: My understanding on your requirement says that triggers like BEFORE DELETE or AFTER DELETE will help.

Comment: Hmm, I can't see in which way a trigger may help to avoid deleting the connections between elements which are NOT in `s1`. Could you give an example of a trigger which adresses this problem?

Comment: If I understand last para of your question correctly then in element table you deleted "e1" with surface_id = 's1' but connection table is still holding an entry with from_elid = 'e1'. If this is correct then you can have a BEFORE DELETE trigger on elements table, and in that trigger you can delete all the rows where from_elid = 'e1', and then delete "e1" from elements table.    What I am not able to understand or probably missing is - in elements table can you have elid as e1 and surface_id as s2? If this is correct then probably you will need to have one more column in connection table.

Comment: One more column in connection table to represent the surface_id.

Comment: No, it is the other way around, the data sent tells me, that the connection between `e1` and `e2` has been deleted (since `{from:e1, to: e2}` is missing), but `e1` and `e2` are still present.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77965/discussion-between-hagrawal-and-rocky).